# Replacing words in tokenized series using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python coding so please be easy on me. I have a tokenized pandas Series that looks like this:

```
reviews = [['bad', 'movie', 'it', 'was', 'turrible'],['bad', 'acting', 'in' 'it'], ['ok', 'experience'],...]
```

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'turrible':'terrible', 'ok':'okay',...}
```

Any words in the reviews that appear in the dictionary keys should be replaced with the dictionary values. So the expected output is:

```
reviews = [['bad', 'movie', 'it', 'was', 'terrible'],['bad', 'acting', 'in', 'it'], ['okay', 'experience'],...]
```

I've searched for hours, and I've tried these solutions, but I am not getting the expected output.

Trial 1:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
result = pattern.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], reviews)

Output: error: incomplete escape \u
```

Trial 2:

```
def replaceWords(text,wdict):
return ''.join(wdict.get(word,word) for word in text)
replaceWords(docs,d)
Output: TypeError unhashable type: 'list'
```

Trial 3 - no error message but did not get expected output:

```
reviews = reviews.replace(d)
```

Trial 4:

```
reviews = reviews.replace(d, regex=True)
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: corrected structure of reviews series

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> reviews = ['bad' 'movie' 'it' 'was' 'terrible','bad' 'acting' 'in' 'it',
   ...:  'okay' 'experience']

>>> reviews
 ['badmovieitwasterrible', 'badactinginit', 'okayexperience']
```

is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: yeah, if I could get the same tokenized words it would be great (e.g. `['bad' 'movie' 'it' 'was' 'terrible', 'bad' 'acting' 'in' 'it', 'okay' 'experience']`)

Comment: @user3599127 I don't understand your question. If your words are not separated by commas, they are implicitly treated as a single word.

Comment: the data was originally sentences in string format `['bad movie it was turrible', 'bad acting in it', 'okay experience']` they were tokenized (i.e. split by each word). Hence each word is in quotes. How can I iterate through each word then?

Comment: do you really want your result to be:  `reviews = ['bad' 'movie' 'it' 'was' 'terrible','bad' 'acting' 'in' 'it', 'okay' 'experience',...]` or would you prefer  `reviews = ['bad movie it was terrible', 'bad acting in it', 'okay experience',...]` ?

Comment: so I was able to separate the words with commas - should make it easier to replace words now?